# Is coffee addiction a problem?

Tags: health

If a person drink coffee for 3 to 4 times a day like a tea and certainly have a coffee addiction. One feels headache when deprived of their coffee for even a single day. Is this a problem to have addiction of coffee?

Comment: I do not think this is a problem. I drink coffee 3-4 times a day. Basically it is a latte. I always feel good. Tea also contains caffeine. No one says that you need to limit the number of cups of tea per day.

Comment: I do not have a problem with it, i love my coffee addiction, we get along splendidly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Coffee addiction is not generally a problem as it is not even an addiction such that people afraid most of the time.**

Caffeine molecules increase and stay at high levels if a person is a regular drinker. During this phase, your body reacts that and adapts to handle more caffeine.

It's like diving deep and staying there for some time. Then, if you rapidly swim up to the surface you caught caisson disease.

Human body is very resilient to changing caffeine levels. It can adapt easily. But, it cannot adapt so fast. If someone is afraid of being addicted, they can slowly decrease the amount of coffee they consume per day.

For example, think of someone drinks 6 cups a day. If decrease rate is a cup per three days, after 15 days daily consumption will be a cup per day. Seems reasonable with no headaches.